# two dependent async requests iOS

Tags: ios

I have two requests (A&B) in a class JSONParser. B is dependent on the response of A. Both the requests return JSON responses. Using these two responses  will create an object C and then I want to return C to a view controller.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: You need to specify what you're actually asking.  This is pretty straightforward, so which bit of it are you having problems with?
I would recommend you post the code you have, and where you're hitting problems.

Answer (score 0):

It's my example. It is very preliminary, but you can figure out how to....
Also you need add error checking.

```
typedef void(^ResultBlock)(id data);

- (NSDictionary *)dataFromURL:(NSString *)url {
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *error;
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    NSDictionary* document = [NSJSONSerialization
                              JSONObjectWithData:responseData //1
                              options:kNilOptions
                              error:&error];
    return document;
}

- (void)getSomeDataWithCompletion:(ResultBlock)completion {

    NSOperationQueue *q = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [q addOperation:[NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock: ^ {
        NSDictionary *response1 = [self dataFromURL:@"server/api1"];

        id result = nil;
        if (response1) {
            NSDictionary *response2 = [self dataFromURL:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", @"server/api2", [response1 objectForKey:@"someParameter"]]];
            result = [response2 objectForKey:@"iFindThisObject"];
        }
        completion(result);
    }]];
}

- (void)performRequest {
    [self getSomeDataWithCompletion:^(id data) {
        NSLog(@"Result %@", data);
    }];
}
```